# Cannot Claim OPOS MSR in JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, hta, opos

I have Posiflex MSR MR2000 Series. I've intalled Posiflex OPOS Control.
I need to manage MSR on html page under IE 8. I use ocx control OPOS.MSR in my JS code / object with regarding CLSID. I have such a code (ActiveX version)

```
    function msrop(){

        try { 
          if ( r = msro.Open('MR1') ) { log ( ER100 + ' ' + 'MSROP' + ' ' + r ); return }
          log(r);
        } 
        catch ( e ) { 
          log ( 'MSROP' , e ) ; return ;
        }

    }

    function msrcl(){
        try { 
          if ( r = msro.Claim(-1) ) { log ( ER100 + ' ' +  'MSRCL' + ' ' + r ); return }
          msro.DeviceEnabled = true ;
          msro.DataEventEnabled = true ;
          log(r);
        } 
        catch ( e ) { 
          log ( 'MSRCL' , e ) ; return ;
        }
    }

    function ol(){

        try { msro = new ActiveXObject ( 'OPOS.MSR' ) ; } catch ( e ) { alert(e) }

        bind ( msro ) ;
    }

    function bind( o ){
        function o::DataEvent(){
            log('<br/>' + '->Tracks read ' + 'T1: ' + o.Track1Data + ' T2: ' + o.Track2Data + 'T3: ' + o.Track3Data + 'T4: ' + o.Track4Data );
            log('<br/>' + '->DataEventEnabled ' + ( msro.DataEventEnabled = true ))
            var d = document.getElementById('track');
            d.innerHTML = o.AccountNumber;
        }
    }
...
    <button onclick="msrop()">Open</button>
    <button onclick="msrcl()">Claim</button>
```

This code works pretty well within HTA application: Claim method returns OPOS_SUCCESS (0). But when I try it as HTM in Internet Explorer 8, Claim method raises exception and object ResultCode property is 104 (OposENoservice). Recall returns ResultCode 102 (OposEClaimed).

I need to get work Claim method properly in Internet Explorer. Why does the same code work different in HTA, which is based on IE??

Comment: Most likely because of `ActiveX`, you need to give your IE more rights to handle ActiveX.

Comment: I gave IE maximum rights, and the security level is low

Comment: can you please share us what you see in your HTM when you add these 2 lines -  alert(document.documentMode); alert(window.navigator.userAgent);

Comment: the results are 8 and "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)" respectively